# Redirect incoming requests to specific URLs in IIS 7

Tags: iis, iis-7, redirect, iis-7.5

I found in IIS HTTP Redirect feature, but I can only redirect all incoming requests to specific destination. Is it possible to redirect incoming requests to specific URLs in IIS? For example:

```
my.domain.com/blog/about -> other.domainxyz.com/site/about
my.domain.com/blog/post/5 -> other.domainxyz.com/site/5
```

**UPDATE**

This is how web.config looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="home" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^$" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://yojimbo87.github.com/" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="about" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^Blog/About$" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://yojimbo87.github.com/about/about.html" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I havent't found URL Rewrite module among the Role Services although HTTP Redirection is there.

Comment: Are both domains bound to the same site .. or they are 2 different sites (I'm asking if domain name should be a condition when creating a rule)?

Comment: Domains are on different sites separated on different machines. I can control only the redirection on the IIS machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This rule will redirect SPECIFIC incoming request to specific URL:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect Specific Page" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^blog/post/5$" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://other.domainxyz.com/site/5" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

---

**UPDATE:**
I have merged them together -- just update it with real URLs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="home" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^$" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://yojimbo87.github.com/" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="about" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^Blog/About$" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://yojimbo87.github.com/about/about.html" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Redirect Specific Page" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^blog/post/5$" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://other.domainxyz.com/site/5" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: When I add this into web.config inside configuration element it starts giving me "500 - Internal server error" no matter which combination of url match I use.

Comment: @yojimbo87 1) You need to have URL Rewrite module installed (which you should have already, considering "IIS 7.5" tag). 2) I hope you have not added it **"as is"**? If you have some rewrite rules already, then you need to add just `<rule>` part into appropriate place. In any case -- the rule is 100% working as I have tested it before posting. If you can -- please provide your web.config (no need for whole content -- just enough to see the structure) so I can guide you where it needs to be placed (in case it is the actual problem).

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: @yojimbo87 See updated answer. If your web.config worked before it should work now as well.

Comment: Still no luck. If I try to go to IIS manager and want to see Failed Request Tracing Rules it gives me an error pointing to web.config. This looks strange cause [other people](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416727/url-rewriting-under-iis-at-godaddy) have also issues with it.

Comment: @yojimbo87 Unfortunately I cannot tell you why it does not work -- I can only confirm that I did copy-paste it from my answer and it worked on both Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 (IIS 7.5 and IIS 7.0 accordingly -- both with URL Rewrite v2 module installed). Maybe access rights? If you have Windows 7 test it locally yourself.

Comment: @yojimbo87 _"Failed Request Tracing Rules it gives me an error pointing to web.config"_ If you can display DETAILED error page, it should point into exact line or display the reason why it rejects web.config. I don't have GoDaddy hosting account and cannot help you on this.

Comment: Sorry for the noise I thought that rewrite module supposed to be installed through Role Services in Server Manager. After I installed the module from [here](http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite) it work as it should. Thanks for patience and help.